# jQuery - Add Code To A Function To Simplify (Stop Repeating Similar Things)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery - So I apologise if this is a silly question :)

I've been challenged with making the code my team uses simple enough to allow less "skilled" people to update it.

I've set variables for everything that needs changing and it works as I expect it to.

My only query is that I'll be running the same 4 things over and over again and I feel like I could achieve what I want in a function?

**Here's a fiddle of it in action with 3 different banners:** http://jsfiddle.net/8ez46mpg/

I repeat this several times over targeting different banners:

```
var $primaryBanner1 = $('#banner-01');
$primaryBanner1.attr('title', primaryOneTxt);
$primaryBanner1.html("<h2>" + primaryOneTxt + "</h2>");
$primaryBanner1.attr('href', primaryOneUrl);
$primaryBanner1.css("background", "url("+primaryOneImg+")");
```

Is there any way I could simplify this into a smaller function?  Rather than having the same 4 lines up to 15 times per page?

Any help would be really great!

Thanks!

Comment: Every jquery object returns itself so you could easy concat them: $primaryBanner1.attr(...).html(...) and so on

Comment: I'll just mention that if this is working code that you want to improve, [codereview.se] might be a better fit for the question.

Comment: Thanks David!  I honestly didn't even know that this existed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a function that performs the repetitive actions and pass in the dynamic variables.

```
function styleBanner(selector, txt, url, img){
  var $el = $(selector);
  $el.attr({
    title: txt,
    href: url
  }).css('background', 'url('+img+')')
    .html('<h2>'+txt+'</h2>');

  return $el;
}

var $primaryBanner1 = styleBanner('#banner-01', primaryOneTxt, primaryOneUrl, primaryOneImg);
```

Comment: I would also suggest adding all parameters (txt, url, img) to options object {txt: 'text', url: 'url'} thus making it easier to extend in future.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for your help Rob!  I'm not too sure what you mean @n0mercy?

Comment: I have updated your script for first example to clarify my suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/20jmfapm/1/